# Directshow returns wrong Frame rate FPS

Tags: c++, winapi, directshow, frame-rate

I want to have the frame rate of a media file using DirectShow.

Currently, I use the following methods which seem inaccurate in some cases:

I add a `SourceFilter` to my graph, enum its pins, then call a `pPin->ConnectionMediaType(&compressedMediaFormat)` and extract `AvgTimePerFrame` out from it. As far as I understand it is the average time per frame expressed in 100 nanoseconds. So, I just divide 10,000,000 / AvgTimePerFrame to get the average FPS of the file.

For those media files which have almost the same frame time for all frames, I get a correct FPS. But for those, which have different frame times for different frames this method returns very inaccurate results.

A correct way to get that would be to get the duration and frame count of the file and calculate the average FPS out of it (frameCount / duration). This is a costly operation however as I understand because calculating the exact number of frames requires passing through the whole file.

I wonder if there is a way to get that frame rate information more accurately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The media files don't have to be of fixed frame rate, in general - there might be variable frame rate. The metadata of the file still has some frame rate related information which, in this case, might be inaccurate. When you start accessing the file, you have the quickly available metadata information about the frame rate. Indeed, to get the full picture you are supposed to read all frames and process their time stamps.

Even though in many it is technically possible to quickly read just time stamps of frames without reading the actual data, DirectShow demultiplexers/parsers have no method defined to obtain the information, so you would have to read and count the frames to get the accurate information.

You don't need to decompress video for that though, and you can also remove clock from the filter graph when doing this, so that counting frames does not require streaming data in real time (frames would be streamed at maximal rate in that case).

Comment: I totally agree with this solution, but I wonder if there is a way to extract that quickly available meta information. For example, when you right-click on the file and select properties then details, it tells you the frame rate. I doubt that it uses that seeking technique because even opening a file of a size of a couple of gigabytes takes no time. I would like to have that value shown in the details section even if is a bit inaccurate. So, I am looking for an alternative of Media Foundation `IMFMediaType->>GetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE)` in DirectShow

Comment: Alternative to this is `AvgTimePerFrame` value from media typem which you mentioned in the question. This is a direct equivalent. Note however, that DirectShow and Media Foundation parsers can extract metadata differently and in some cases the extracted values may vary.

Comment: That is exactly what happened to me. For some media file Media Foundation and  Right click Properties -> Details show 8 FPS while calculating it with `AvgTimePerFrame` ends up with 24 FPS.

Comment: Since it's parser implementation dependent, you don't have a lot of options here. You requested a value and you are supposed to trust it. As frame rate may be variable, the value is more of informational kind and you might be misinformed with the rest of the feed being well playable. And, again, the accurate frame times in general case can only be obtained by streaming the file through.